# How do I avoid having JSONP returns cached in an HTML5 offline application?

Tags: iphone, caching, manifest, jsonp, offlineapps

I had good luck with cached offline apps until I tried including data from JSONP endpoints. Here's a tiny example, which loads a single movie from the new Netflix widget API:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="main.manifest">
   <head>
      <title>Testing!</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <p>Attempting to recover a title from Netflix now...</p>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function ping(r) { alert('API reply: ' + r.catalog_title.title.regular); }
   var cb = new Date().getTime();
   var s = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
   s.src = 'http://movi.es/7Soq?v=2.0&output=json&expand=widget&callback=ping&cacheBuster=' + cb;
   alert('SCRIPT src: ' + s.src);
   s.type = 'text/javascript';
   document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].appendChild(s);
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

... and here's the contents of my manifest, `main.manifest`, which contains no files and is only there so my browser knows to cache the calling HTML file.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
```

Yes, I've confirmed that my server is sending the manifest down with the correct content type, `text/cache-manifest`.

The app works fine--meaning both alerts show--the first time I run it, but subsequent runs, even with the attempt at cache-busting in line 10, seem to be attempting to load the script from cache no matter what the query string is.  I see the alert showing the script source, but the callback never fires.

If I remove the manifest link from line 2 and reset my browser--being Safari and the iPhone Simulator--to clear cache, it works every time.  I've also tried alerting the number of SCRIPT tags in the page, and it's definitely seeing both the existing and dynamically-created tag in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, found it in the spec, of all the crazy places:

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#concept-appcache-onlinewhitelist-wildcard

I needed to add http://movi.es/ to the NETWORK: section of my manifest.  Complete file now looks like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

NETWORK:
http://movi.es/
```

... and seems to hit the network every time.